# Redmine plugin: Uninitialized constant I18n

Tags: ruby, plugins, redmine

We just installed [Redmine Charts](http://github.com/mszczytowski/redmine_charts/tree/master) and the associated OpenFlashChart plugin but when we start the Ruby server, we get the error below. Our steps were to:

1. Download the tar file for charts
2. Untar into `$REDMINE_ROOT/plugins dir`
3. `$REDMINE_ROOT/script/plugin install http://svn.pullmonkey.com/plugins/trunk/open_flash_chart/`
4. Try to start server

```
=> Booting WEBrick...
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:276:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Redmine::I18n (NameError)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/local/apps/redmine-0.8/vendor/plugins/mszczytowski-redmine_charts-e3c5010466d7585d987bc1018e94daee90906a5d/lib/redmine_charts/line_data_converter.rb:4
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:102:in `require_or_load'
     ... 27 levels...
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.2/lib/commands/server.rb:39
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine's `I18n` is a recent addition for multiple languages.  It's only available in the trunk version of Redmine, the 0.8.x versions of Redmine use the older `GLoc` plugin.

You have a couple of options to fix this:

- Upgrade to the trunk version of Redmine
- Ask the developer to make the plugin compatible with the released version of Redmine (I personally do this for my Redmine plugins)
- Or try to fix the `I18n` errors yourself

To fix the errors, you will need to go through the code and replace all mentions of `I18n` with `GLoc` and then create an older version of the translations in the plugins `lang/` directory.

Eric Davis

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of redmine_charts, it requires Redmine::I18n - there are several instances of "include Redmine::I18n".

See also http://www.redmine.org/news/22 for more information about Rails, Redmine, and I18n.

It appears that you may have versioning (Rails and Redmine) issues.